# Why is bind_front copying

Tags: c++

I thought that bind_front will perfect forward but it seems to copy. What am I missing here:

```
class CustomObject {
public:
    // Constructor
    CustomObject(int value) : value(value) {
        std::cout << "Constructor: " << value << std::endl;
    }

    // Copy Constructor
    CustomObject(const CustomObject& other) : value(other.value) {
        //this is called
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor: " << value << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int value;
};

void func(const CustomObject& a, int b, int c) {
    std::cout << ", " << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    CustomObject A{ 5 };
    auto boundFunc = std::bind_front(func, A, 2, 2);
    boundFunc();
   
    return 0;

}
```

I though it will perfec forward to func and not move/copy

Comment: Do you expect `boundFunc` to store `A` for later without copying it?

Comment: I dont expect to store it at all. Just dangle if destroyed

Comment: So you expect it to keep a reference? That never happens in the standard library.

Comment: ok so I think I got it. In this case it is jsut the same as bind but without the placeholders autobinding left to right. Is this correct?

Comment: @molbdnilo how about forward_as_tuple this does store references. Cannot we just store it there and std::apply after

Comment: `bind` family of functions capture arguments by value. The reason is temporary nature of references; when the original object gets out of scope, references become dangling and become UB sources. In special occasions where you are sure UB won't happen, `std::ref` and `std::cref` can store (const) reference to arguments. References are the safety bottle neck in modern C++. Be cautious around them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front)

> The arguments to `std::bind_front` or `std::bind_back` are copied or moved, and are never passed by reference unless wrapped in `std::ref` or `std::cref`.

In your example though, this works perfectly:

```
auto boundFunc = std::bind_front(func, std::cref(A), 2, 2);
```

Comment: but how is that different from std::bind then except being more restrictive. Seems like it does the same in this case? It does not perfect forward. Bind docs says absolutely the same https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: @KimGiacinto - It's less verbose in very common cases. Compare `std::bind_front(&C::func, this)` to `std::bind_front(&C::func, this, _1, _2, _3, /* However many more */)` - It's not meant to be that much different otherwise.

Comment: good point. Thanks.

Comment: Also, not as error prone. std::bind will silently drop unmentioned arguments. I've seen an actual bug from that.